# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested SCRAM-based authentication, but no password was provided

Tags: java, sql, pgadmin

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

public class prog1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String dbname = "BD22";
        String dbuser = "postgres";
        String password = "12345";
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/" + dbname;

        try {
            BufferedReader in;
            in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ));
            System.out.println("Insira um novo passageiro");
            System.out.print(">> Nome: "); String nomePassageiro = in.readLine();
            System.out.print(">> Morada: "); String destinopretendido = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("Nome: " + nomePassageiro + "    Morada: " + destinopretendido);
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            c.setAutoCommit(false);
            Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
            String sql = "INSERT INTO passageiros(nomeP,destinopretendido) VALUES ('" +
                    nomePassageiro + "','" + destinopretendido + "');";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            stmt.close();
            c.commit();
            c.close();
            System.out.println("Estudio " + nomePassageiro + " inserido.");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

When I start the code I can write everything, but when the program starts the "phase" in which it should add to the database what was written, the title error appears and when I debug it, it appears: Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:54160', transport: 'socket'
Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by putting on line 18 (which had the command- Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url); ) the following command- Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url, dbuser, password);

Comment: Can you add more explanation on this answer so that it can be more useful for others ?